# Angular lazy loading issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement lazy loading and trying to lazy load sign in component but when sign in link is clicked i am getting exception 'Cannot match any route'.

```
//app.component.html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Register / Login</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a routerLink="signin" routerLinkActive="nav-link active">Sign In</a></li>
      <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="help" routerLinkActive="nav-link active">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>



//app.module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelpComponent } from './help/help.component';

const route: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HelpComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'lazymodule', loadChildren: './login-register/login-register.module#LoginRegisterModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'help', component: HelpComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HelpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(route)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }



//login-register.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SignInComponent } from './sign-in/sign-in.component';
import { FormsModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/router';

const route: Routes = [
  {path: 'signin', component: SignInComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(route)
  ],
  declarations: [SignInComponent]
})
export class LoginRegisterModule { }
```

**signin component** lies in **app->login-register->sign-in** folder. Please advice.

Comment: I think your `loadChildren` path is wrong. Try `loadChildren: 'app/login-register/login-register.module#LoginRegisterModule'`

Answer (score 1):

Use fat arrow function, then you don't have to worry about path of the module

e.g.

```
{ path: 'lazymodule', loadChildren: () => LoginRegisterModule }
```

and your **routerLink** should be

```
<li><a routerLink="/lazymodule/signin" routerLinkActive="nav-link active">Sign In</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ng5-Lazy-loading-bug-cli-1.7.1 bug:

angular-cli1.7.1 have issue to laod lazy laoding in string

{ path: 'user-panel', loadChildren: './user-panel/user-panel.module#UserPanelModule', },  -> will give error some time.

to
{ path: 'user-panel', loadChildren: () => UserPanelModule, },

import {UserPanelModule} from '/path-of-module'   in routing.ts
make the lazy loading into preloader module-> load the module as component level - module as component.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is incorrect .
try this :

```
//app.component.html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Register / Login</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a routerLink="lazymodule/signin" routerLinkActive="nav-link active">Sign In</a></li>
      <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="help" routerLinkActive="nav-link active">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```